# OxyPlot нужно построить диаграмму по точкам

Tags: c#, winforms, oxyplot

Как в OxyPlot построить диаграмму по точкам.
если есть у кого-нибудь примеры можете скинуть?
есть просто точки и еще формула политропы и не знаю как можно реализовать это
помогите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.
построение по точкам
или как работает LineSeries

Comment: Ну [вот](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/getting-started/hello-windows-forms.html) же пример. Там даже картиночки есть и в конце ссылка на код.

Comment: @Vasek там построение идёт через FunctionSeries и где точки он рисует параллельную линию оси х

Comment: Нужно что то на подобии [этого](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd456709(v=vs.100))?

Comment: @Vasek нужно что бы строился график по точкам и без использования FunctionSeries

Answer (score 0):

Построение по точкам с помощью LineSeries в OxyPlot

```
var pm = new PlotModel()
        {
            Title = "LineSeries"
        };

        var lineSeries1 = new LineSeries();
        lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 10));
        lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(40,80));
        pm.Series.Add(lineSeries1);
        plot1.Model = pm;
```